# Counting lines with non-printable characters with BSD

Tags: bash, macos, grep, bsd

I am trying to sort out some bad data in a file on a BSD-style system, which means that I do not have the -P option in grep.  I have 7 million lines of data, and a subset has some strange characters.  If you to a "less" on the file, you'll see something like this:

```
290437430@89
9^@0333465@88
290348389@87
290342818@8^@
```

The ^@ is from a bad character that is not ASCII that showed up due to noise on the serial line when the characters were sent.  These lines are corrupt, and I want to count the number of corrupt data strings.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do you get if you use `xxd` on one of the corrupt lines?

Comment: @123 Just skimming some of it I have 0x00, 0x03, 0x87, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Chepner's suggestion adding following solution here:

```
grep -c '\x00' Input_file
```

Following 2 will give only literal characters only.

If you want to only count `@` then a simple `grep` could help you on same.

```
grep -c "@"  Input_file
```

Or in case of counting `^@` then following may help you on same.

```
grep -c "\^@"  Input_file
```

Comment: They are likely placeholders for unprintable characters, not literal `^@`'s

Comment: The file doesn't actually contain `^` and `@`; `^@` is how `less` displays a null byte. `grep -c $'\0' Input_file` should (assuming `bash`) give the count the OP wants.

Comment: @chepner, thanks sir, added your suggestion now in post.

Comment: Ah, even better. According to `man re_format`, you can use `\x00` to match a null byte; no shell tricks needed. `grep -c '\x00' Input_file`.

Comment: @chepner, done II captain, nice solution given here by you sir, learning for me :)